# My Required Field Validator Not Working On An Input With A Watermark

Tags: asp.net

I have a required field Validator on a text-box that has a  Watermark on it.  I am using Ajax Toolkit ValidatorCalloutExtender.  The user can still click the submit button without any validation occurring.  I have researched online but could not find a useful info.  I am not sure what i am missing here.

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="403px"
                                Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldEmail" runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="*** This is a required field ***" ControlToValidate="TextBox6" Display="None" 
                                Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtenderEmail" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldEmail" HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>

                               <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="AuthorEmail_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"
                                    Enabled="True" WatermarkText="<<Type the first 4 letters of the first name to autopopulate>>"
                                    TargetControlID="TextBox6">
                                </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>


                                <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoComplete00" runat="server" EnableCaching="true"
                                    BehaviorID="AutoCompleteExa" MinimumPrefixLength="3" TargetControlID="TextBox6"
                                    ServicePath="../AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" CompletionInterval="1000"
                                    CompletionSetCount="10" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
                                    CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
                                    DelimiterCharacters=";, :" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the InitialValue of the RequiredFieldValidator as the WatermarkText. Modify the markup of your requiredfieldvalidator like below and see if it helps.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*** This is a required field ***" ControlToValidate="TextBox6" Display="None" InitialValue="<<Type the first 4 letters of the first name to autopopulate>>" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: yea i tried this method before and i tried again now but getting "Microsoft Jscript runtime error".  i have also tried another method where i add 2 required field validator, one with the initial value set and the other one without the initial value but still did not work.

Comment: okay, i know what my issue is.. i wrapped my detailview  with UpdatePanel so if i remove the UpdatePanel then it will work but it won't work if i keep it in there.  Yes and i said the initial value in the required validator.  Any suggestion please??